# serving static files from servlet filter

Tags: java, servlets, file, static, servlet-filters

I have to serve a static file (based on the request uri) from a servlet filter, if the response from the servlet has some "hint" to do so (that's not the point). So my question is, what is the best way to serve a static file from a servlet.Filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one way: Forward the response to the static file.

EDIT

```
filterConfig.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/path/to/static-file.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with "forward the response"?